# PHP-FPM is not being restarted properly from a Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I am having this weird problem with PHP-FPM. First of all, I am not an expert on PHP. I'm builing an app, and PHP will only communicate with MySQL to push and pull data.

The problem:

I have a Dockerfile where I'm making some changed in PHP-FPM config, and one of the lines is to reload PHP-FPM. Actually when you install PHP-FPM, it is not running, so I do:

```
RUN service php7.3-fpm start
```

When the app starts and I check PHP-FPM, it is not running. I had this issue before (with php7-0-fpm), I had resolved it by doing:

```
service php7.0-fpm stop && service php7.0-fpm start
```

But now, when I do it, it is still stopped.

So, I started reading and someone advised to put it in the CMD command, along with the main command. I did, and it worked:

```
CMD service php7.3-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Now, the problem is that it is not taking the new configuration. When I access the machine, and I manually do `service php7.3-fpm reload` it starts working.

I tried putting it in the Dockrfile as well, but no luck. Any idea? I would like to resolve the first issue as well (I don't want to restart PHP-FPM from the CMD. It would be preferable to do it with a RUN layer in docker).

**EDIT**

Another weird thing is that when I do `service php7.3-fpm start` manually, it doesn't work, but it works when I do `/etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm start`. Seems to work, when I do it in the CMD line:

```
CMD /etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:buster

LABEL maintainer="me"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
nginx \
default-mysql-client \
php7.3-fpm \
php7.3-mysql

RUN sed -i.bak "s/;clear_env = no/clear_env = no/g" /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf && \
sed -i.bak "s/;php_flag\[\display_errors\]\ = off/php_flag\[\display_errors\]\ = on/g" /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

COPY ./html/ /var/www/html/

RUN rm /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80

CMD service php7.3-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Comment: if you want to do it in RUN layer as you said read about `docker entrypoint`. also pls provide your Dockerfile to see where is you configuration for FPM is set

Comment: ENTRYPOINT is for running an executable file. My app starts by starting nginx. I have pasted my Dockerfile, but is it relavant?

Comment: Note that docker containers usually don't have an init system; containers are not VM's and in most cases, they should be considered a "sandboxed process", which means that there's a single process (or a single _main_ process) running in them. You may want to look at the official PHP images on Docker Hub; https://hub.docker.com/_/php, which also has an NPM variant (albeit no nginx installed, which is assumed to be running in its own container; https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.3/buster/fpm

Comment: the thing is that the app was working fine with 7.0. Now I don't want to make major changes. Probably this is not the best implementation though

Answer (score 2):

Execute a command or restart php-fpm using `RUN directive` will not effect because each layer runs in a separate shell.

The best way is to copy the config file from host, rebuild the image and then run the container.

for Example

```
FROM debian:buster
COPY config/php7.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
COPY config/fpm/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/
COPY config/fpm/pool.d /usr/local/etc/pool.d
```

Also better to run the separate container for each process, rule of thumb single process per container.

You CMD seem fine it starts PHP and Nginx both.

To verify process inside your container add

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install procps -y
```

then run

```
docker exec -it your_container_id bash -c "ps -aux"
```

Comment: thanks. I'll do that. I am realizing that fpm is not always starting properly, although putting it in the CMD line. I am going to ask another question regarding that. It is crazy. The same image (with the same docker image ID), tagged differently, don't behave the same. Does this make any sense?

Comment: If during running container, image configuration not changes by ENV or mount files then the same Image should behave consistently. BTW you ask the question to review by community

Comment: https://blog.joshwalsh.me/docker-nginx-php-fpm/ I will recommend this approach to go