# Same docker image (with the same imahe ID) tagged differently behave different

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I don't know if this makes any sense, but I was making some tests, to create a working docker image. It started to work, so I thought that's it! I changed the tag to something relevant, and the new image is not working.

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
repo           expv7               46e8eb6fe0f0        8 minutes ago       336MB
repo           exp1                46e8eb6fe0f0        8 minutes ago       336MB
```

Now, when I run this images, `repo: expv7` works fine, while `repo: exp1` doesn't.

All I did was tagging the working image and pushing it to Docker Hub.

**EDIT**

To all those, who just write clichés, like I don't have enough info, and the one who voted to close this question. What does it matter what's the error? The fact is that there is ONE image that behaves differently in the SAME environment, without any reason. Let's say it's a hello-world that works on one, and doesn't on another. Does this help?

If you know why, perfect. Thanks. If not, skip this, and still perfect.

Comment: Could you expand on what's happening; what is "not working"? Is an error message printed?

Comment: sure. this is the question, from where this one derived: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182202/php-fpm-is-not-being-restarted-properly-from-a-dockerfile/58182872

Comment: check `docker logs <containerid>` for some logs that may explain. If the behavior is different, usually the culprit is with an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint) script.

Comment: I know what's failing; with the working one php-fpm is running, with the other one it failed to start. But why? It's the same build.

Comment: Note that docker containers usually don't have an init system; containers are not VM's and in most cases, they should be considered a "sandboxed process", which means that there's a single process (or a single _main_ process) running in them. You may want to look at the official PHP images on Docker Hub; https://hub.docker.com/_/php, which also has an NPM variant (albeit no nginx installed, which is assumed to be running in its own container; https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.3/buster/fpm

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you have given it is hard to tell  what the problem is. you can try this command `docker exec -i -t container-id bash` or`docker exec -i -t container-name bash` and check the logs of that service. hope that's helpful